# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Resultset: next

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

We are migrating our application from Hibernate deault pool to `C3P0`.

Our application was running correctly in default pool configuration. but with C3P0 it displays below exception.

> > 16:45:35,890 | DEBUG | com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils - Attempted to convert SQLException to SQLException. Leaving it alone. [SQLState: 08003; errorCode: 17010]
> >     java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Resultset: next
> >         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:214)

Our configuration for C3P0 is below

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">200</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

And we are using `C3P0.0.9.1.2 jar` for the configuration.

Thanks for providing assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a trace message. c3p0 will log a great deal at DEBUG levels. c3p0 libraries are intended to be logged at INFO in general.

All the message is telling you is that c3p0 observed an Exception that, in order to conform with JDBC APIs, was going to need to be rethrown as an SQLException. However, it was already an SQLException, so c3p0 left it alone. It looks as though your application called next() on a closed result set. If this message isn't followed by some evidence of the Exception, your app probably handles (or swallows or does something with) it. Hopefully it does the right thing.

The easiest solution is to set the logging level for loggers in com.mchange to INFO.

And please, upgrade to c3p0-0.9.2.1.